# idea to form constraint for the below situation

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi

I have to allocate resources to team A, team B and team C based on some constraints. Because of the constraints team A, B or C can or cannot get resource which is perfectly acceptable solution.

if all teams gets at least some resource allocated, we need to maintain some resource differential between the teams.

(1) Team A vs Team B 100 (Team A resource should be less than Team B by 100)
(2) Team A vs Team C 50 (Team A resource should be less than Team c by 50)
(3) Team B vs Team C 70 (Team B resource should be less than Team c by 70)

If Team A  has no resource allocated, constraint (1) and (2) can be ignored.
If Team B has no resource allocated, constraint (1) and (3) can be ignored.
If Team C has no resource allocated, constraint (2) and (3) can be ignored.

How do I model the condition, in such a way Maximum resources are allocated and the conditions are also met.

Answer (score 0):

> Ra,Rb,Rc variables continues or integers(>=0) ressources for teams respectively A,B,T;
>   Xa,Xb,Xc binary variables for teams respectively A,B,T;
>   Xa = 1 if Team A has allocated ressources, Xa =0 if not.
>   Xb = 1 if Team B has allocated ressources, Xb =0 if not.
>   Xc = 1 if Team C has allocated ressources, Xc =0 if not.
>   Ma1, Ma2, Ma4, Mb1, Mb3, Mb4, Mc2, Mc3, Mc4 are big parameters.
>   Contraints : Ra + 100 <= Rb + Ma1(1-Xa) + Mb1(1-Xb) 
>                Ra + 50 <= Rc + Ma2(1-Xa) + Mc2(1-Xc)
>                Rb + 70 <= Rc + Mb3(1-Xb) + Mc3(1-Xc)
>                Xa<=Ra, Xb<=Rb, Xc<=Rc
>                Ra<=Ma4Xa, Rb<=Mb4Xb,  Rc<=Mc4Xc
>                max(Ra + Rb +Rc)